# Fade in Animation plays twice

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm enabling the visibility of a button (from `GONE` to `VISIBLE`), and animating its alpha value, whenever the user types on an `EditText`:

```
private void ShowSendButton()
    {
        if (sendbtn.Visibility != ViewStates.Visible)
        {
            sendbtn.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            sendbtn.Animate().Alpha(1.0f);
        }

    }
```

Whenever the `EditText` is empty, the button fades out and its visibility is set to `GONE`, like this:

```
private void HideSendButton()
        {
            if (sendbtn.Visibility != ViewStates.Gone)
            {
                sendbtn.Animate().Alpha(0.0f).SetDuration(150).Start();
                sendbtn.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
        }
```

The `ShowSendButton` animation always plays twice, i.e. right after the animation is finished, the button's alpha value resets back to 0.0 and plays the fade animation again.

This does not happen in the `HideSendButton` animation.

This is the code that triggers the animations:

```
editText.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.AfterCount != 0)
                {
                    ShowSendButton();
                }
                else
                {
                    HideSendButton();
                }

            };
```

This is the button XML:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:alpha="0"/>
```

Comment: have you tried animating first then make Visible? in ShowSendButton?

Comment: Put your alpha above your visibility, then set to visible.

Comment: @Greg Sadly, that didn't work. The button appears instantly and approximately 0.2s later the animation plays once.

Comment: @Greg I'm using xamarin.android, not WPF.

Comment: @NicodeOry Sorry, misread your tag.

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
private void ShowSendButton()
{
    if (sendbtn.Visibility != ViewStates.Visible)
    {
        sendbtn.ClearAnimation();
        sendbtn.Animate().Alpha(1.0f).SetDuration(200).WithStartAction(new Runnable(() => {
            sendbtn.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        })).Start();
    }
}

private void HideSendButton()
{
    if (sendbtn.Visibility != ViewStates.Gone)
    {
        sendbtn.ClearAnimation();
        sendbtn.Animate().Alpha(0.0f).SetDuration(200).WithEndAction(new Runnable(() =>
        {
            sendbtn.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        })).Start();
    }
}
```

Tested on a device and it seems to go well.

Hope it helps.-

Comment: The hide animation shows some artifacts (it looks like it plays twice but it's hard to tell). The show animation appears instantly and after about 0.1-0.2s the animation plays.

Comment: Let me ask you, Are you using an emulator or a real device? Animations on emulators might not display right so it's convenient using a real device.

Comment: I'm using both. I looked more closely and the animation is played twice (both the hide and show one). I'm confused as to why my approach works and yours doesn't.

Comment: If you put a break point... could it be the method is being called twice?

Comment: As strange as it sounds, both methods are only called once.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be partially fixed by changing my `ShowSendButton` code to

```
private void ShowSendButton()
    {
        if (sendbtn.Visibility != ViewStates.Visible)
        {
            sendbtn.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            sendbtn.ClearAnimation();
            Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
            fadeIn.Duration = 50;
            sendbtn.Animation = fadeIn;

        }

    }
```

Works fine, but I can't seem to change the animation duration (`fadeIn.Duration = 50` doesn't work). Whatever value I set it to, it always plays at about 0.2s.

Comment: Try a higher number like 500.

Comment: @apineda Sorry, I should have clarified. The animation runs slower than  I want it to (at about 0.2s). Nothing happens if I change the duration..